# MySQL count value by ID

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure if the title explains what I am trying to do correctly however I was unable to word it.

I am trying to create an output for a some graphs. The output I am aiming for is just the total value of some rows in a mySQL table grouped by a category ID. My tables are as follows:

```
Transactions:

TransactiondID | TransactionName |TransactionCategory| Value
*************************************************************
       1       |  GenericText1   |      1            | 30
       2       |  GenericText2   |      1            | 38
       3       |  GenericText2   |      2            | 38
```

And my Reference Data for TransactionCategory

```
TranCatID | TransCatName
*************************
    1     | Tranportation
    2     | Petrol
```

So what I want to do is do is a SUM of the value field by each category. So I would get an output of.

```
Category       | Value
****************************
Transportation | 68
Petrol         | 30
```

I got this but it does not work. I think it is completely incorrect but wanted to show my attempt.

```
SELECT SUM( `TransactionValue`) AS Value, 
transaction_category.transaction_category
FROM Transactions 
JOIN transaction_category on Transactions.TransactionID = transaction_category_id
```

Comment: I think your missing the "GROUP BY transaction_category_id" at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by either "TransactionCategory" or "TranCatID" will give you the desired result shown as follows:

```
SELECT TransactionCategory.TransCatName, SUM( `Value`) AS Value FROM Transactions  JOIN TransactionCategory on Transactions.TransactionCategory = TransactionCategory.TranCatID GROUP BY TransactionCategory.TransactionCategory;

or

SELECT TransactionCategory.TransCatName, SUM( `Value`) AS Value FROM Transactions  JOIN TransactionCategory on Transactions.TransactionCategory = TransactionCategory.TranCatID GROUP BY TransactionCategory.TranCatID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT TransactionCategory.TransCatName,
    SUM(Transactions.Value) as Value
FROM Transactions
    LEFT JOIN TransactionCategory ON TransactionCategory.TranCatID = Transaction.TransactionCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
SELECT tc.TransCatName Category, SUM(t.Value) as Value
FROM TransactionCategory tc
LEFT JOIN Transactions t ON tc.TranCatID = t.TransactionCategory
group by tc.TransCatName
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/136aa3/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
Category       | Value
-----------------------
Petrol         | 38
Transportation | 68
```

Please notice the `SUM` for **PETROL**, it should `38` as above, which is wrongly written `30` in your question description!